# python conda pystan, expects older version of mpfr library?

Tags: python, conda, libraries, mpfr, pystan

Sorry if this is not the right place to ask, but it seems to be a general installation question rather than a pystan question...

I am trying to run some simple examples of pystan, a Python Bayesian inference package, and it consistently crashes. So e.g. when I run the "Getting started, Example 1" example at https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html (except I have added "verbose=True" to the line which gives the error), at the line

```
sm = pystan.StanModel(model_code=schools_code, verbose=True)
```

I get a long error trace, which begins with:

```
INFO:pystan:COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL anon_model_19a09b474d1901f191444eaf8a6b8ce2 NOW.
INFO:pystan:OS: darwin, Python: 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct  5 2017, 02:28:52) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)], Cython 0.26.1
Compiling /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpQqJaIl/stanfit4anon_model_19a09b474d1901f191444eaf8a6b8ce2_8277449399850120616.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpQqJaIl/stanfit4anon_model_19a09b474d1901f191444eaf8a6b8ce2_8277449399850120616.pyx
building 'stanfit4anon_model_19a09b474d1901f191444eaf8a6b8ce2_8277449399850120616' extension
creating /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpQqJaIl/var
creating /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpQqJaIl/var/folders
creating /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpQqJaIl/var/folders/6l
creating /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpQqJaIl/var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp
creating /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpQqJaIl/var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T
creating /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpQqJaIl/var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpQqJaIl
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/peter/miniconda2/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DBOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_TR1 -DBOOST_NO_DECLTYPE -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -I/var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpQqJaIl -I/Users/peter/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pystan -I/Users/peter/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pystan/stan/src -I/Users/peter/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math -I/Users/peter/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/eigen_3.3.3 -I/Users/peter/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.69.0 -I/Users/peter/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/sundials_4.1.0/include -I/Users/peter/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/peter/miniconda2/include/python2.7 -c /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpQqJaIl/stanfit4anon_model_19a09b474d1901f191444eaf8a6b8ce2_8277449399850120616.cpp -o /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpQqJaIl/var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpQqJaIl/stanfit4anon_model_19a09b474d1901f191444eaf8a6b8ce2_8277449399850120616.o -O2 -ftemplate-depth-256 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-uninitialized -std=c++1y
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mpfr/lib/libmpfr.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0/7.2.0/cc1plus
  Reason: image not found
gcc: internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6 (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues> for instructions.
```

I am using miniconda on Mac OS X 10.12.5. I get an identical error whether I run python2 or python3. (Above trace is python2; Python3 is python 3.6.8, installed on July 25).

The key error seems to be that it expects to find the file /usr/local/opt/mpfr/lib/libmpfr.4.dylib . When I look in that directory, I see a file libmpfr.6.dylib , and libmpfr.dylib which is a symbolic link to libmpfr.dylib , but no libmpfr.4.dylib

I wonder if something horrible is going on with assumed library paths, like it is assuming the libraries used by /usr/bin/python rather than ~/miniconda2/bin/python (which is what I use for python, because ~/miniconda2/bin is at the front of my bash shell PATH).

So... do I need to install the older (rev 4) version of libmpfr ? If so, how?

UPDATE: after seeing the reply (below), I updated gcc (to 9.2) and conda. but now it crashes somewhere else...

```
INFO:pystan:COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL anon_model_19a09b474d1901f191444eaf8a6b8ce2 NOW.
INFO:pystan:OS: darwin, Python: 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 29 2018, 19:04:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)], Cython 0.28.5
Compiling /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpw103deo3/stanfit4anon_model_19a09b474d1901f191444eaf8a6b8ce2_6187777314581226416.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpw103deo3/stanfit4anon_model_19a09b474d1901f191444eaf8a6b8ce2_6187777314581226416.pyx
building 'stanfit4anon_model_19a09b474d1901f191444eaf8a6b8ce2_6187777314581226416' extension
creating /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpw103deo3/var
creating /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpw103deo3/var/folders
creating /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpw103deo3/var/folders/6l
creating /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpw103deo3/var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp
creating /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpw103deo3/var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T
creating /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpw103deo3/var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpw103deo3
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/peter/miniconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/peter/miniconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DBOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_TR1 -DBOOST_NO_DECLTYPE -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -I/var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpw103deo3 -I/Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystan -I/Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystan/stan/src -I/Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math -I/Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/eigen_3.3.3 -I/Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.69.0 -I/Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/sundials_4.1.0/include -I/Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/peter/miniconda3/include/python3.6m -c /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpw103deo3/stanfit4anon_model_19a09b474d1901f191444eaf8a6b8ce2_6187777314581226416.cpp -o /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpw103deo3/var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpw103deo3/stanfit4anon_model_19a09b474d1901f191444eaf8a6b8ce2_6187777314581226416.o -O2 -ftemplate-depth-256 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-uninitialized -std=c++1y
In file included from /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpw103deo3/stanfit4anon_model_19a09b474d1901f191444eaf8a6b8ce2_6187777314581226416.cpp:642:
In file included from /Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
In file included from /Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12:
In file included from /Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1824:
/Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
 ^
In file included from /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpw103deo3/stanfit4anon_model_19a09b474d1901f191444eaf8a6b8ce2_6187777314581226416.cpp:646:
In file included from /Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystan/stan_fit.hpp:12:
In file included from /Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.69.0/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp:10:
In file included from /Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.69.0/boost/date_time/time_clock.hpp:17:
In file included from /Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.69.0/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17:
/Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.69.0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:370:174: error: no member named 'move' in namespace 'std'
    BOOST_CONSTEXPR shared_ptr( boost::detail::sp_internal_constructor_tag, element_type * px_, boost::detail::shared_count && pn_ ) BOOST_SP_NOEXCEPT : px( px_ ), pn( std::move( pn_ ) )
                                                                                                                                                                        ~~~~~^
/Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.69.0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:927:27: error: no member named 'move' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'modf'?
    return shared_ptr<T>( std::move(r), p );
                          ^~~~~~~~~
                          modf
/usr/include/math.h:407:15: note: 'modf' declared here
extern double modf(double, double *);
              ^
In file included from /var/folders/6l/mw9lfs_51h74dfvg458rrn1c0000gp/T/tmpw103deo3/stanfit4anon_model_19a09b474d1901f191444eaf8a6b8ce2_6187777314581226416.cpp:646:
In file included from /Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystan/stan_fit.hpp:12:
In file included from /Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.69.0/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp:10:
In file included from /Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.69.0/boost/date_time/time_clock.hpp:17:
In file included from /Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.69.0/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17:
/Users/peter/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pystan/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.69.0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:937:27: error: no member named 'move' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'modf'?
    return shared_ptr<T>( std::move(r), p );

                          modf
/usr/include/math.h:407:15: note: 'modf' declared here
extern double modf(double, double *);
              ^
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to python. The error comes from the GCC installed on your machine under `/usr/local/Cellar`, which expects `libmpfr.4.dylib`, which corresponds to MPFR 3.x. You need to either install a newer GCC that expects `libmpfr.6.dylib` (MPFR 4.x), or install MPFR 3.x. But note that MPFR 3.x is old, has unfixed bugs, and is no longer maintained.

Comment: (Well, it is python related in the sense that I am having problem with a python package). I updated GCC (to 9.2, and also updated conda) and now get another error. The log is above, if you or anyone else has any idea. .

Comment: @PeterB In the logs you added, I can see that you're still using GCC 4.2.1. The new version of conda probably expects a more recent compiler, thus you now get this error first.

Comment: And yet GCC 9.2 is installed on my machine. Which is why I think it is something to do with paths.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it is using GCC 4.2.1. I think it is a note about Clang 4.0.1, in which "GCC 4.2.1 Compatible" is an adjective.

Comment: @PeterB Yes, indeed, it is Clang (I got confused by the highlight). And yes, you need to adjust the paths, but I don't know the best way of doing that on your machine (that could be in the `.profile`, but not necessarily).